# How does my PR contains the work from another dudes branch?

Tags: git, pull-request

I need some help understanding a git cock up:

Basically I created a branch, let's call it XXX off the master branch.

Some dude afterwards then merged his changes into the remote master branch. So now my local master branch does not have the changes in the remote master branch.

I then ran git pull origin master from branch XXX. This pulled in what looked like the changes from the remote master branch I think (I can't remember now).

I finished my work. Then I committed my changes and I created a PR. But my PR contains my work and also the work that the other dude did! Why is that? Is it because my local branch is behind and the PR is based off the local master branch?

Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

When you did your `git pull origin master`, you merged the remote master into your branch, including their changes.

Doing that you did not update your local master branch, but working branch.

So when you finally created a pull request from your branch back into `origin/master`, that PR also contains their changes. However, since their changes are already present on `origin/master`, they should not be shown as diff in the PR - unless their merge was reverted.

Comment: OK, so the bit about pulling in the changes from the remote part I was correct about. The other dude did not revert his changes. I just can't figure out how his changes are showing up in my PR

Comment: Could it be a bug in GitHub?

Comment: I would not suspect a bug in GitHub in this case. Without seeing some actual history, there's not much we can say about this. A PR lists all **changes** between the branch-to-merge and its target; if their changes show up as changes in your PR, something else must have happened on `origin/master` in the meantime.

Comment: OK, I think I know what has happened. Basically I missed one commit that the dude did. He actually did two commits. The first commit is fine. Because what I normally do is go into local master branch and do a git pull. I then go into my XXX branch in this case and then do a git pull origin master. So now local and remote master are in sync. But this time I didn't do that. I just did git pull origin master in my XXX branch, finished my work and created a PR. But the PR is based on local master history which does not have the dude's latest changes. So the PR has the dude's changes/